# How to I resolve command not found in AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, command-line-interface

All of a sudden no linux command(ls, vi, etc..) is working in AWS EC2 instance and I get message saying command not found.

I had launched an EC2 instance and all linux commands were working fine.
I then uploaded some files to EC2 and extracted them(setting up my environment).

I made following changes to the ~/.bashrc file

```
export M2_HOME=/home/ec2-user/apache-maven-3.6.0
export JAVA_HOME=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_151
export ANT_HOME=/home/ec2-user/apache-ant-1.9.13
export PATH=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.7.0_80/bin:/home/ec2-user/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin
export JBOSS_HOME=target/wildfly-run/wildfly-11.0.0.Final
```

and I executed below command in my AWS EC2 instance.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After this linux commands(ls, vi, cat, etc..) are not working, however "which", "pwd" commands are working.

Can someone help to me to correct the PATH settings so that my commands start executing normally

Comment: A possible fix would be to use `/bin/ls` instead of `ls`, given that these usual commands are in `/bin.`

Answer (score 6):

You should append the original PATH to the additions you made (using the $PATH variable), like below:

> export PATH=/home/ec2-user/jdk1.7.0_80/bin:/home/ec2-user/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:$PATH

Comment: sudo command doesn't work, says command not found, any suggestion?

Comment: sudo is in /usr/bin so check if that's in the path.  However, by using the $PATH variable, it should have been included automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Changing value of path as below sorted out all the issues

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin:/home/ec2-user/jdk1.7.0_80/bin:/home/ec2-user/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:/home/ec2-user/apache-ant-1.9.14/bin
```

below is the system default path

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin
```